# rails 3 json not rending user id

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a simple
@user = User.all

User has firstName, lastName, email and all the devics stuff.

But when I render it as json, I don't get the user.id.  Just get all the other info.

```
format.json { render :json => @users, :except => [:encrypted_password, :last_sign_in_at, :last_sign_in_ip, :reset_password_sent_at, :reset_password_token, :remember_created_at, :sign_in_count], :include => [:profile, :authentications] }
```

Comment: mikhailov and Zach where right, after looking at API reference and using :only instead of :except, it cleared things up.  Noticed was only happening with my User controller so think it was devise blocking it, which would make sense for security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **@users.to_json(:except....)**, not **@users, except**

see the [API reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect Rails doesn't provide the ID to try and help against mischievous use.

The usual way is to have a different key for use with objects in the API.